# Minimal memory footprint for SSL connection (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, performance, memory, ssl, openssl

I'm using a Node.js client to connect to thirdparty SSL servers. Currently, memory footprint is about ~130kb per connection. Node.js uses OpenSSL for this.
How can I reduce this footprint to the minimal possible size?
I've read that Google has done some work on the subject a while back:
https://www.imperialviolet.org/2010/06/25/overclocking-ssl.html

Is this still relevant? Any pointers? 
Many thanks!